# Javafx Labeled labelPaddingProperty - Adding triangles in the upper left or right corners

Tags: javafx

I'm trying draw a triangle in the upper left or right corner of a Labeled (really a TableCell) like Excel does. The JavaFX labelPadding documentation says:

The padding around the Labeled's text and graphic content. By default labelPadding is Insets.EMPTY and cannot be set to null. **Subclasses may add nodes outside this padding and inside the Labeled's padding.** This property can only be set from CSS.

Thus I thought I could set the style to 10px on top and then add the Polygon to the Labeled, but while the padding works, the Polygon doesn't draw. For example, if I inserted this into a scene I would expect to get a Pink corner above Hello:

```
public class JxLabeled extends Labeled {
    public JxLabeled() {
        setText("Hello");
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0 });
        polygon.setFill(Color.PINK);
        getChildren().add(polygon);
        setStyle("-fx-label-padding: 10 0 0 0;");
    }
}
```

Any ideas where the Polygon node should be added based on the above documentation?

PS- I realize that I could create a Group or StackedPane to do this, but since I'm using this in TableView and overriding TableCell, I was trying not to create a compound object for each cell.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the way `TableCell` initializes it's contents.

`TableCell` extends `Control` and therefore the children are added when the skin is initialized which happens during the first layout pass. `TableCellSkin` **replaces** existing children and therefore removes your `Polygon` from the child list.

You need to use your own skin to prevent this. (Note that `TableCellSkin` is part of the `com.sun` packages):

```
public class ExcelCellSkin<S, T> extends TableCellSkin<S, T> {

    private final Polygon polygon;

    public ExcelCellSkin(TableCell<S, T> tableCell) {
        super(tableCell);

        this.polygon = new Polygon(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0);
        polygon.setFill(Color.PINK);
        this.polygon.setManaged(false);
        getChildren().add(polygon);
    }

}
```

```
public class ExcelCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    {
        setStyle("-fx-label-padding: 0 0 0 10;");
    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new ExcelCellSkin<>(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setText(Objects.toString(item, ""));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I found that I had to add a repair method to ExcellCellSkin that was called in Excelcell:updateItem to re-add the Polygon since it seems that it was removed when rows were added to the table and other times. But since the Skin isn't always establish when the updateItem is called, I also used setSkin(createDefaultSkin) if getSkin was null. Thanks again!!!!